# Ionic Facebook Login

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have recently been migrating my app from Meteor JS to Ionic Framework.  One that has been a struggle is finding a really good plug and play Facebook login oAuth.

Currently it just needs to control view access based on logged in or logged off.  As well as returning the Facebook user id.

I have searched for many with Ionic and the best I have gotten to work so far is ng-cordova. But it is rather confusing because it references another git repo from Wizcorp, and seems to run several errors upon setup.

So I am curious is anyone has a better tutorial to follow, or an overall sure fire plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I did facebook login using Openfb+ InAPP Browser .
First create App on [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com) and then use [In App Browser plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/)

Comment: thanks @nikolas . I did many think with facebook like login ,post ,like , comment ,so if you have any query then let me know, thanks ,close your issue too ,

Answer (score -1):

And adding to the answer, you have to build the login flow, manually.

[Facebook: Build the login flow manually](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow)

Comment: Why did I get a -1?